# Coalesce value bound to object's key into parent's value

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, jsonb

I have a `PostgreSQL 12.x` database. There is a column `data` in a table `typename` that contains JSON. The actual JSON data is not fixed to a particular structure; these are some examples:

```json
{"emt": {"key": " ", "source": "INPUT"}, "id": 1, "fields": {}}

{"emt": {"key": "Stack Overflow", "source": "INPUT"}, "id": 2, "fields": {}}

{"emt": {"key": "https://www.domain.tld/index.html", "source": "INPUT"}, "description": {"key": "JSONB datatype", "source": "INPUT"}, "overlay": {"id": 5, "source": "bOv"}, "fields": {"id": 1, "description": "Themed", "recs ": "1"}}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to come up with is a (database migration) script that will find any object with the keys `key` and `source`, take the actual value of `key` and assign it to the corresponding key/value pair where the object was originally bound to. For instance:

```json
{"emt": " ", "id": 1, "fields": {}}

{"emt": "Stack Overflow", "id": 2, "fields": {}}

{"emt": "https://www.domain.tld/index.html", "description": "JSONB datatype", "overlay": {"id": 5, "source": "bOv"}, "fields": {"id": 1, "description": "Themed", "recs ": "1"}}
```

I started finding the rows that contained `"source": "INPUT"` by using:

```sql
select * from typename
where jsonb_path_exists(data, '$.** ? (@.type() == "string" && @ like_regex "INPUT")');
```

...but then I'm not sure how to update the returned subset or to loop through it :/

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but here is the `update` statement:

```sql
update typename
set data = jsonb_set(data, '{emt}', jsonb_extract_path(data, 'emt', 'key')::jsonb, false)
where jsonb_typeof(data -> 'emt') = 'object'
  and jsonb_path_exists(data, '$.emt.key ? (@.type() == "string")')
  and jsonb_path_exists(data, '$.emt.source ? (@.type() == "string" && @ like_regex "INPUT")');
```

There are probably better ways to implement that `where` clause, but that one works ;)

One downside is that I had to figure it out how many *keys* are involved in the update and align it with the number of `update` statements; e.g.: in the original example there were two keys: `emt` and `description` — so it should have been two `update` statements.